# Need help understanding paragraph from a book on complex geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am having trouble understanding this paragraph on page $7$ in the book Complex Geometry by Daniel Huybrechts:

> Any holomorphic function $f(z)$ in one variable with a zero of order
>   $d$ at the origin can be written as $z^d \cdot h(z)$, with $h(0) \neq
>  0$. If we let this decomposition depend on extra parameters, then the
>   polynomial $z^d$ becomes an arbitrary polynomial of degree $d$ whose
>   coefficients depend on the parameter. This is due to the fact that a
>   zero of order $d$ of $f_0(z_1)$ might deform to a collection of zeros
>   of $f_w(z_1)$ whose orders sum up to $d$.

We have previously defined $f_w(z_1) := f(z_1, z_2, \dots , z_n)$, where $w = (z_2 , \dots , z_n)$, and $f$ is a function of $n$ variables.

I take it that the decompositon comes from a Laurent expansion of $f$ in a neighbourhood containing $0$.

However, I do not understand what he means by letting the decomposition depend on extra parameters, or how a zero "deforms" to a collection of zeros of $f_w(z_1)$.

As far as I can tell the notation $f_0$ is not previously defined in the text. Edit: I realize now that the author must mean take $w = (0, \dots , 0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Paramater' refers to $w$. Namely he considers a family of functions $(f_w(z))_w$ parametrized by $w$.

'A zero of order $d$ deforms to a collection of zeros ...' means that the polynomial $z^d$ for the parameter $0$, with root $0$ of order $d$, becomes a polynomial $P_w(z)$ of degree $d$, with roots whose orders sum up to $d$.

**Example :** consider the family $(f_w(z))_w$, where $f_w(z) = z^2-wz$.
Then for the parameter $w=0$, $f_0$ has roots $z=0$ of order $2$.
But for $w \neq 0$, the function $f_w$ has roots $z=0$ and $z=w$ each of order $1$ (hence their order sum up to 2). So in this example, the set of zeros $\{ 0 \}$ of order $2$ (for the parameter $w=0$) 'deforms' to the set $\{ 0, w\}$ each of order 1.

The point of your paragraph is that, in a general family of functions, the set of zeros might change but the sum of the orders is always constant.

For some highlight, I suggest you read the next theorem (Weierstrass preparation theorem).